# Test if there are files matching a pattern in order to execute a script

Tags: shell-script, shell, files, wildcards, test

I am trying to write an `if` statement to test whether there are any files matching a certain pattern. If there is a text file in a directory it should run a given script.

My code currently:

```
if [ -f /*.txt ]; then ./script fi
```

Please give some ideas; I only want to run the script if there is a `.txt` in the directory.

Comment: Are you sure "the directory" is supposed to be `/`?  Also, you're missing a semicolon before `fi`.

Comment: The cleanest robust solution I've encountered is to use `find` as explained [here on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4264351/411282).

Answer (score 52, accepted):

```
[ -f /*.txt ]
```

would return true only if there's **one** (and only one) non-hidden file in `/` whose name ends in `.txt` and if that file is a regular file or a symlink to a regular file.

That's because wildcards are expanded by the shell prior to being passed to the command (here `[`).

So if there's a `/a.txt` and `/b.txt`, `[` will be passed 5 arguments: `[`, `-f`, `/a.txt`, `/b.txt` and `]`. `[` would then complain that `-f` is given too many arguments.

If you want to check that the `*.txt` pattern expands to at least one non-hidden file (regular or not), in the `bash` shell:

```
shopt -s nullglob
set -- *.txt
if [ "$#" -gt 0 ]; then
  ./script "$@" # call script with that list of files.
fi
# Or with bash arrays so you can keep the arguments:
files=( *.txt )
# apply C-style boolean on member count
(( ${#files[@]} )) && ./script "${files[@]}"
```

`shopt -s nullglob` is `bash` specific (`shopt` is, `nullglob` actually comes from `zsh`), but shells like `ksh93`, `zsh`, `yash`, `tcsh` have equivalent statements.

With `zsh`, the test for *are there files matching a pattern* can be written using an anonymous function and the `N` (for `nullglob`) and `Y1` (to stop after the first find) glob qualifier:

```
if ()(($#)) *.txt(NY1); then
  do-something
fi
```

Note that those find those files by reading the contents of the directory, it doesn't try and access those files at all which makes it more efficient than solutions that call commands like `ls` or `stat` on that list of files computed by the shell.

The standard `sh` equivalent would be:

```
set -- [*].txt *.txt
case "$1$2" in
  ('[*].txt*.txt') ;;
  (*) shift; script "$@"
esac
```

The problem is that with Bourne or POSIX shells, if a pattern doesn't match, it expands to itself. So if `*.txt` expands to `*.txt`, you don't know whether it's because there's no `.txt` file in the directory or because there's one file called `*.txt`. Using `[*].txt *.txt` allows to discriminate between the two.

Now, if you want to check that the `*.txt` matches at least one *regular* file or symlink to regular file (like your `[ -f *.txt ]` suggests you want to do), or that all the files that match `*.txt` are *regular* files (after symlink resolution), that's yet another matter.

With `zsh`:

```
if ()(($#)) *.txt(NY1-.); then
  echo "there is at least one regular .txt file"
fi
if ()(($#)) *.txt(NY1^-.); then
  echo "there is at least one non-regular .txt files"
fi
```

(remove the `-` if you want to do the test prior to symlink resolution, that is consider symlinks as non-regular files whether they point to regular files or not).

Comment: `[ -f /*.txt ]` is quite fast in comparison to `compgen`.

Comment: @DanielBöhmer `[ -f /*.txt ]` would be wrong, but in my test on a directory that contains `3425` files, `94` of which are non-hidden txt files, `compgen -G "*.txt" > /dev/null 2>&1` appear to be as fast as `set -- *.txt; [ "$#" -gt 0 ]` (20.5 seconds for both when repeated 10000 times in my case).

Comment: Failure: The "standard shell `sh` solution" counts non-regular files (i.e: directories) also. Any directory that match the pattern will also be included.

Answer (score 17):

You could always use `find`:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -name "*.txt" 2>/dev/null | grep -q . && ./script
```

Explanation:

- `find .` : search the current directory
- `-maxdepth 1`: do not search subdirectories
- `-type f` : search only regular files
- `name "*.txt"` : search for files ending in `.txt`
- `2>/dev/null` : redirect error messages to [`/dev/null`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki//dev/null)
- `| grep -q .` :  grep for any character, will return false if no characters found.
- `&& ./script` : Execute `./script` only if the previous command was successful ([`&&`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Lists))

Comment: `find` only returns false if it has trouble looking for files, not if it doesn't find any file. You want to pipe the output to `grep -q .` to check if it finds something.

Comment: @StephaneChazelas you're quite right of course. Weird though, I'd tested it and it seemed to work. Must have done something strange because it doesn't any more. When will find "have trouble finding files"?

Comment: @terdon, like when some directory is inaccessible, or I/O errors or any error returned by any system call it makes. In that case, try after `chmod a-x .`.

Answer (score 17):

A possible solution is also Bash builtin `compgen`. That command returns all possible matches for a globbing pattern and has an exit code indicating whether any files matched.

```
compgen -G "/*.text" > /dev/null && ./script
```

I found this question while looking for solutions that are faster though.

Comment: Good find! If you're in a multi-byte locale, you can improve it slightly with `LC_ALL=C compgen -G "*.txt" > /dev/null`.

Answer (score 9):

Here's a one liner to do it:

```
$ ls
file1.pl  file2.pl
```

#### files exist

```
$ stat -t *.pl >/dev/null 2>&1 && echo "file exists" || echo "file doesn't exist"
file exists
```

#### files don't exist

```
$ stat -t -- *.txt >/dev/null 2>&1 && echo "file exists" || echo "file don't exist"
file don't exist
```

This approach makes use of the `||` and `&&` operators in bash. These are the "or" and "and" operators.

So if the stat command returns a `$?` equal to 0 then the first `echo` is called, if it returns a 1, then the second `echo` is called.

#### return results from stat

```
# a failure
$ stat -t -- *.txt >/dev/null 2>&1
$ echo "$?"
1

# a success
$ stat -t -- *.pl >/dev/null 2>&1
$ echo "$?"
0
```

This question is extensively covered over on stackoverflow:

- [Test whether a glob has any matches in bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2937407/test-whether-a-glob-has-any-matches-in-bash)

Comment: Why use the non standard `stat` when `ls -d` can do the same?

Comment: I thought `ls -d` lists a directory? Didn't seem to work when I just tried listing a directory with files in it `ls -d *.pl` for example.

Comment: You can replace the statement to the left of `&&` by `ls *.txt` and it will work as well.  Make sure you send the stdout and stderr to `/dev/null` as suggested by @slm.

Comment: If you use `ls *.txt` and there are no files present within the directory this will return a `$? = 2`, which will still work with the if then, but this was one of my reasons for choosing `stat` over `ls`. I wanted a 0 for success, and a 1 for a failure.

Comment: `ls -d` is to list directories instead of their content. So `ls -d` just does the `lstat` on the file, just like GNU `stat` does. What non-zero exit status commands return on failure is system specific, it makes little sense to make assumptions on them.

Comment: Is it OK to assume that 0 is a success, and anything else is a failure then?

Comment: It's the shell that expands the wildcard, your stat or `ls -d` is just there to return an error when the pattern expands to itself when there's no matching file. In this case, because the pattern matches itself, it will generally work (though could fail if some files have disappeared or appear in between the time the shell reads the content of the directory and `stat` does an `lstat(2)` on those files, or if `lstat(2)` fails for any reason), but in cases like `stat -- *.[cC]`, if there's no `c` nor `C` file in the current directory, but there's a file called `*.[cC]`, your `stat` will succeed.

Comment: Sorry if I"m being dense but I don't understand the difference still b/w `stat` vs. `ls -d`. The man page states the following for `lstat()` - lstat() is identical to stat(), except that if path is a symbolic link, then the link itself is  stat-ed

Answer (score 7):

As Chazelas points out, your script would fail if wildcard expansion matches more than one file.

However, there is a trick I use (*even I don't like it very much*) to get around:

```
PATTERN=(/*.txt)
if [ -f ${PATTERN[0]} ]; then
...
fi
```

How it works?

Wildcard expansion will match an array of filenames, we get the first one if there are some, otherwise null if no match.

Comment: IMO this is the least bad answer here. They all seem pretty horrible though, as though a basic feature is missing from the language.

Comment: @plugwash it's intentional... *nix shell scripts have some basic flow control and a few other odds and ends but at the end of the day it's job is to glue together other commands. If bash sucks... it's because the commands you use from it suck

Comment: That's the wrong logic (and you're missing quotes). That checks if the first matching file is a regular file. It may well be a non-regular files but there may be several other `.txt` files that are of type _regular_. Try for instance after `mkdir a.txt; mkfifo b.txt; echo regular > c.txt`.

Answer (score 1):

I find this approach pretty simple and readable in `bash`, without invoking too many magic bashisms:

```
if [[ $(ls /*.txt 2>/dev/null) != "" ]]; then ./script; fi
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple as:

```
cnt=`ls \*.txt 2>/dev/null | wc -l`
if [ "$cnt" != "0" ]; then ./script fi
```

`wc -l` counts the lines in the expanded wildcard.

Comment: Downvote: This collects an amazing number of beginner antipatterns in a small amount of code. [You should not parse `ls` output](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs) and almost never examine `$?` directly because `if` already does that. Also, [using `wc` to see if something happened](http://www.iki.fi/era/unix/award.html#wc) is similarly misdirected.

Answer (score 0):

I like the previous array solution, but that could become wasteful with large numbers of files - the shell would use a great deal of memory to build the array, and only the first element would ever be tested.

Here is an alternate structure that I tested yesterday:

`$ cd /etc; if [[ $(echo * | grep passwd) ]];then echo yes;else echo no;fi
yes
$ cd /etc; if [[ $(echo * | grep password) ]];then echo yes;else echo no;fi
no`

The exit value from the grep appears to be determining the path through the control structure. This also tests with regular expressions rather than shell patterns. Some of my systems have the "pcregrep" command which allows much more sophisticated regex matches.

(I did edit this answer to remove an "ls" in the command substitution after reading the above criticism for parsing it.)

Answer (score 0):

A more versatile method is:

```
IFS=
shopt -s nullglob
txt=('/'*'.txt')
if [ -f "$txt" ]; then ./script fi
```

But this method works only if there is a single match.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use `ls` command and properties of " and () symbol:

```
if [ "$( ls *the folder you want to check* | grep *any pattern* )" != "" ]; then
    : *do anything you like*
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use a simple case statement within a for loop.
Given this list of files:

```
a1.txt
a2.jpg
y4.txt
z5.doc
```

Then execute `my_script` only against files with `txt` extension:

```
for file in * ; do
    case "${file}" in
        *.txt) ./my_script "${file}"
        ;;
    esac
done
```

Answer (score -1):

A way, in [bash](/questions/tagged/bash): if you want to know if there's some files matching the pattern `*.txt`, then consider:

```
(
    shopt -s nullglob
    compgen -W *.txt &>/dev/null

    case $? in
        0) echo 'one match' ;;
        1) echo 'more than one match' ;;
        3) echo 'no match at all' ;;
    esac
)
```

The *subshell* `( )` is here only to reset `shopt` as default settings. Can use

```
shopt -u nullglob
```

too.

## Note

It's different than `compgen -G`, because here we can discriminates more cases

Comment: No, that's that how `compgen -W` is meant to be used nor how it works.

Comment: Removed the mention 'proper way', but still relevant answer. This code works as intended in my answer. Just a little hack

Comment: `compgen -W something` splits `something` on $IFS and prints the resulting words one per line, except the empty ones. `compgen -W` does give a syntax error indeed. `compgen -W something something-else` could do anything, especially  if `something-else` starts with `-` (think of a `-Creboot .txt` for instance).

Comment: Ah, yes, sad that `compgen -W -- *.txt` not helps here

Answer (score -3):

if you want to use an if clause, evaluate the count:

```
if (( `ls *.txt 2> /dev/null|wc -l` ));then...
```