# Check of folder's content never succeeds

Tags: bash

The bash script snippet

```
folder="some folder's name"
a="$folder/"*".pdf"
if [ "$a" != "$folder"'/*.pdf' ]
then
    echo check
fi
```

never prints `check`.

I'd expect it to print `check` iff there is at least 1 file whose name ends in `.pdf` in folder `$folder`.

`echo $a` and `echo "$folder"'/*.pdf'` print exactly what I'd expect them to print: The former prints the matched paths iff there is at least 1 `*.pdf` file in the specified folder and otherwise prints what the latter prints. The latter always prints the name of the specified older concatenated with `/*.pdf`.

1. Why does bash behave like that?
2. How do I make it work?

Comment: The proper way to do it is described here: [Test if there are files matching a pattern in order to execute a script](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/79301/22142)

Comment: With bash, that condition (`[ "$#" -gt 0 ]`) always passes. It think this is because bash just doesn't replace the asterisk if there is no match, so there always is at least 1 result.

Comment: No. If you bother reading the answer there you'll see there's a `shopt -s nullglob` _before_ that condition.

Comment: Oh, you're right. I'm sorry. With that option set, it works. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

This expression `"$folder/"*".pdf"` will expand to all possible filenames that end with `.pdf`. 
Why? The **`*`** sign retains its special meaning i.e. **globbing**.

While this string `"$folder"'/*.pdf'` is just a concatenation of 2 separate strings `"$folder"` and `'/*.pdf'`.
 As **`*`** sign enclosed in single quotes - it ***loses*** its special meaning.

---

According to your main goal ***check if the current folder has at least one `.pdf` file*** and printing some `"pdf file found!"` phrase on success:

```
if [ ! -z `find foldername -type f -name "*.pdf" -print -quit` ]; then 
    echo "pdf file found!"
fi
```

Comment: That's the plan. So the condition should be true if there are PDFs in the specified folder, right? (Note the exclamation point.)

Comment: @UTF-8, your final goal is to `echo "check"` if the current folder has at  least one `*.pdf` file, right?

Comment: Yes, that's what I'm trying to do.

Comment: @UTF-8, see my update

Comment: This fails on a number of occasions. I'm not entirely sure what occasions, though: https://pastebin.com/nasQePMx

Comment: @UTF-8, enclose the condition in double brackets [[ ! -z `find foldername -type f -name "*.pdf" -print -quit` ]]`

Answer (score 1):

Your `if` statement doesn't work, because `$a` enclosed in double quotes is just a string containing a `*` (compare `echo "$a"` with `echo $a`). If you remove the double quotes, your `if` statements fails as soon as there are more than one files matching.

don_crissti's link has good solutions.

Comment: We both agree that the right expression doesn't depend on the folder's contents, right? If there is no file in the folder, bash doesn't replace the wild card `*` in the variable assignment. So my plan is to check whether that replacement happened.

Comment: Yes, Bash does not replace `*` when there is no match (corrected my answer). I still don't think you can handle the case of >1 matches (many pdf files in the folder) this way. If you are not enclosing `$a` in `"`, the `if` statement is going to fail with `too many arguments`. If you are enclosing `$a` in `"`, `*` is not going to be resolved/replaced by file names. Thus, I don't think `if` in combination with file name expansion is a good idea. I have been using `ls`' exit status before, but there other options.