# glob variable mandatorily in the double quotes

Tags: bash, variable, wildcards

This link: [Wildcards inside quotes](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/67757/wildcards-inside-quotes)
in my case not solve the problem.
The file "a.sh" contain:

```
file="path with wildcard*"
```

The file "b.sh" contain:

```
. a.sh
[ -f "$file" ] && echo ok
```

Because

```
"$file"
```

not expand wildcard, instead

```
$file
```

expand wildcard, but with error: "binary operator expected"

How do I solve this puzzle? It is not possible to take the wildcard out of the double quotes.

Edit:
I want achieve a single match from wildcard. If there are more matches, the condition must return false, in any case not must return an error.

Comment: `binary operator expected` indicates your unquoted `$file` brought two words. `[ -f … ]` expects exactly one path. If it gets two (so with `-f` there are three words inside `[ ]`), `[` assumes the middle argument is a binary operator (which somehow compares two arguments: its neighbors). If it got even more, the error would be `too many arguments`. The problem is not that `*` doesn't expand; the problem is that `$file` expands to too many entities. Maybe because there are two matching files; maybe because of word splitting. `path with wildcard*` is three words, the last one can expand to more.

Comment: Please see [Test whether a glob has any matches in bash](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2937407/10765659) and [its duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6363441/10765659). And [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/79301/108618).

Comment: It's unclear what your intention with the test is. Is it to test the existence of _any_ regular file matching the pattern?  Note that the `-f` test only works on single files. What if the pattern matches a range of filetypes (directories, regular files, named pipes, etc.), should the test fail (because there was at least one file that was not a regular file), or should it succeed (because there was at least one regular file)?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Test if there are files matching a pattern in order to execute a script](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/79301/test-if-there-are-files-matching-a-pattern-in-order-to-execute-a-script)

Comment: No.............

Comment: Note that `. a.sh` looks for `a.sh` in `$PATH`, not in the current directory (though in the case of `bash` when not in `sh` mode, it will fall back to using the `a.sh` in the current directory if it can't be found in `$PATH`). Change to `. ./a.sh` if you want to source the `a.sh` file in the current directory.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to store in an *array* the list of files resulting from the expansion of a glob pattern stored in variable, in `bash`, that would be:

```
pattern='path with wildcard*'

IFS= # disable splitting

shopt -s nullglob # make globs that don't match any file expand to nothing
                  # instead of the unexpanded pattern.

files=($pattern) # here using split+glob (unquoted expansion in list context)
                 # with the splitting disabled above.
```

Or to assign the `$files` array directly without using a `$pattern` scalar variable:

```
shopt -s nullglob # make globs that don't match any file expand to nothing
                  # instead of the unexpanded pattern.

files=('path with wildcard'*)
```

Then you can test if that list is empty with:

```
if [ "${#files[@]}" -gt 0 ]; then
  echo it did find some files
fi
```

If you want to check, that among those files, at least one is a regular file (after symlink resolution), you could do:

```
has_regular_files() {
  local file
  for file do
    [ -f "$file" ] && return
  done
  false
}

if has_regular_files "${files[@]}"; then
  echo there was at least one regular file in the list
fi
```

To check that it matches only one file and that that file is a regular file:

```
if [ "${#files[@]}" -eq 1 ] && [ -f "${files[0]}" ]; then
  echo one and only one file matches and it is regular.
fi
```

To check that it matches at least one regular file and that all the matched files are regular:

```
only_regular_files() {
  [ "$#" -gt 0 ] || return
  local file
  for file do
    [ -f "$file" ] || return
  done
}

if only_regular_files "${files[@]}"; then
  echo at least one regular file and all are regular.
fi
```

With the `zsh` shell, you can use glob qualifiers to match by file type:

```
if ()(($#)) $~pattern(N-.); then
  print at least one regular file in the expansion of the pattern.
fi
```

- contrary to `bash`, `zsh` doesn't do implicit split+glob upon unquoted parameter expansions. Here we're asking for globbing (but not splitting) with `$~pattern`.
- We append the `(N-.)` glob qualifier, `N` for `nullglob` so that if the glob matches no file, it expands to nothing `.` to test for *regular* files only (to the exclusion of any other type of file), `-` so that that test be done *after* symlink resolution so it would also match on files that are symlinks to regular files (like your `[ -f "$file" ]` would).
- the expansion of that glob is passed as arguments to an anonymous function, `() {body} args` where the `{body}` is `(($#))`.
- `((expr))` is a ksh-style arithmetic expression evaluation operator, that returns true if the expression evaluates to a number other than 0. Here, the expression is `$#`, that is a special parameter than expands to the number of positional parameters, in this case the number of arguments of that anonymous function, so the number of files that result from that glob expansion.

Comment: I not have understand. What is the splitting in this case? Can I have an example, please?

Comment: @MarioPalumbo, https://mywiki.wooledge.org/WordSplitting and https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/131766/170373

Answer (score 2):

```
[ -f $file ] && echo ok
```

This would expand the variable, wordsplit, and expand *all* matching files. You might end up with `[ -f filethis filethat ]`, and `filethis` isn't a binary operator, so you get the error.

Even if there are no matches, and `$file` expands to nothing, you get `[ -f ]` which is a test to see if `-f` is a non-empty string. It is, so the result is true.

Expand the filenames to an array or to the positional parameters and count the matches:

```
file="path with wildcard*"
IFS=
set -- $file
echo "matched $# files"
```

You have to change `IFS` there if you have whitespace in the pattern, because the split happens before filename expansion, so the above would have two constant words and one glob pattern. Also an unmatched pattern would remain as-is, so we need to check for that.

You could hide this in a function:

```
only_one() {
    local IFS=
    set -- $1
    if [ $# = 1 ] && [ -f "$1" ]; then return 0; fi
    return 1
}
```

and then run

```
if only_one "$file"; then 
    ...
fi
```

Comment: My solution is more speed and comes to the same solution.

Comment: @MarioPalumbo, less typing, surely. I doubt there's a significant difference in runtime, and if that even matters, I'd suggest using something else than the shell, it's always slow. :) Note that passing through `read` can cause issues if someone creates filenames with newlines or backslashes in their names. Dealing with that kind of stuff is pretty much the biggest issue in shell programming, as far as I see, and arrays are often the best way to deal with that.

Comment: Note that using `[ -f "$1" ]` means that it restricts it to *regular* files (tested after symlink resolution). That would return false if the glob matches one file but that file is not regular (like a director file, a fifo file, a socket file, a device file...).

Comment: If the glob doesn't match any file, `set  -- $file` `bash` will still store one element in the positional parameter array unless you set the `failglob` or `nullglob` option.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas i have tested this command with a symlink. It works.

Comment: @ilkkachu Based on (thank you) you reply, i have modified the answer, look and says me if like it.

Comment: @MarioPalumbo, it works if the only match is a symlink pointing to a regular file, but not if the match is a directory, or a symlink to a directory, or one of the more special files. Also, it returns falsy if there are two matches, one regular file and one not. Probably a corner case, but the point is that it's hard to exclude files based in type in the expansion itself (at least in Bash).

Answer (score -2):

I have solved with:
The file "a.sh" contain:

```
file=('path with wildcard'*)
```

The file "b.sh" contain:

```
. a.sh
[ -f "$file" ] && echo ok
```

Result: Ok

Comment: I want achieve a single match from wildcard. If there are more matches, is right that the answer's condition returns false.

Comment: Thanks Stephane Chazelas, what is a good method for expand wildcards and put in a variable?

Comment: See my answer...

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas Check now, i have modified my reply.

Comment: That's much better. You're now checking that the first file whose name starts with `path with wildcard` in the current directory is a regular file (after symlink resolution). That's because (confusingly) in `bash` like in `ksh`, `$file` is actually short for `${file[0]}` (the element of indice 0, that's different from *every* other shell). Note that after `mkdir 'path with wildcard1'; ln -s /dev/null 'path with wildcard2'; echo text > 'path with wildcard3'`, that would not output OK because the first matching file is not a *regular* file in that case. That would change if you swapped 1 and 3.

Comment: I not care about not expansion in case of file not found, is good for me and in my case, when a file is found, i am sure that there aren't delimitetor within wildcard, IN MY CASE. Thank you very much @StéphaneChazelas