# Why does using double brackets "[[" to check if wildcard matched files exists fail, while single brackets "[" work?

Tags: bash, shell, wildcards, test, pattern-matching

Let's say I generate a two directories with text files in each like so

```
mkdir "Directory1"
mkdir "Directory2"
touch "Directory1/fileclass1_"{1..5}".txt"
touch "Directory1/fileclass2_"{1..5}".txt"
touch "Directory2/fileclass1_"{1..5}".txt"
touch "Directory2/fileclass2_"{1..5}".txt"
```

Suppose I verify all the files are inside by doing

```
A=( "Directory1" "Directory2" )
B=( "fileclass1" "fileclass2" )
for a in "${A[@]}"; do
    for b in "${B[@]}"; do
        for i in {1..5}; do
            name="${a}/${b}*${i}.txt"
            [[ ! -e $name ]] && echo "$name Does Not Exist"
        done
    done
done
```

This returns

```
Directory1/fileclass1*1.txt Does Not Exist
Directory1/fileclass1*2.txt Does Not Exist
...
```

However, if I instead replace the double brackets with singles, I get

```
A=( "Directory1" "Directory2" )
B=( "fileclass1" "fileclass2" )
for a in "${A[@]}"; do
    for b in "${B[@]}"; do
        for i in {1..5}; do
            name="${a}/${b}*${i}.txt"
            [ ! -e $name ] && echo "$name Does Not Exist"
        done
    done
done
```

which returns nothing, indicating all files are indeed there.

Why is it in this case, the double brackets fail, while single brackets work? I was under the assumption I should always employ double brackets, is the wildcard in string matching creating something I shouldn't have?

Comment: From `man bash`: *Word splitting and pathname expansion are not performed  on  the words  between  the  `[[`  and  `]]`*

Comment: FWIW neither syntax provides a robust way to do what you want - for better alternatives, see [Test if there are files matching a pattern in order to execute a script](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/79301/test-if-there-are-files-matching-a-pattern-in-order-to-execute-a-script)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `-e` conditional operator tests whether a file with the given name exists. It doesn't do any pattern matching. `[[ -e fileclass1*1.txt ]]` tests whether there is a file called `fileclass1*1.txt` with a literal asterisk in the name, not whether there is at least one file matching the wildcard pattern `fileclass1*1.txt`.

With a single bracket `[ ! -e $name ]`, since `$name` is unquoted, the value of `name` undergoes wildcard substitution and word splitting. If the value of `name` is `Directory1/fileclass1*1.txt`, the effect depends on how many files match the wildcard pattern.

- If the pattern doesn't match any file, it's left unexpanded. Then the `-e` operator sees the file name `Directory1/fileclass1*1.txt`, which doesn't exist, so `[ ! -e $name ]` is true.
- If the pattern matches a single file, it's replaced by that file's name. Then the `-e` operator sees that file name, which exists¹, so `[ ! -e $name ]` is false.
- If the pattern matches two or more files, it's replaced by the list of matching file names, which results in a syntax error in the conditional. In this case, `[ ! -e $name ]` displays an error message and returns a failure status.

The effect is different with `[[ -e $name ]]` because `[[ … ]]` is special syntax (whereas `[` is an ordinary command whose arguments are expanded normally). No word splitting or wildcard expansion is done inside `[[ … ]]`.

To solve your actual problem, see [Test if there are files matching a pattern in order to execute a script](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/79301/test-if-there-are-files-matching-a-pattern-in-order-to-execute-a-script)

¹  <sub>Except in the unlikely case that due to a race condition, the file is removed between the time the shell lists the directory content to expand the wildcard pattern, and the time the `-e` operator checks for the file's existence.</sub>